# How to read csv file of 1.3 GB with text information into Python's pandas object?

Tags: python, pandas, csv, text, large-data

I am trying to read a csv file of 1.3 GB with two columns and 19,333 rows into Python's pandas dataframe using 'pd.read_csv', but it keeps generating error messages saying 'CParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: out of memory', and I have tried many recommendations posted online, like using 'chunksize', but it doesn't seem to work, only to produce 'Kernel died, restarting'. Here is the output while running 'pd.read_csv'.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import os

os.chdir("/home/swhan/Downloads")

CORPUS = pd.read_csv('10k_2005_2008_file.csv')
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-1-8136c4f0354a>", line 7, in <module>
    CORPUS = pd.read_csv('10k_2005_2008_file.csv')

  File "/home/swhan/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 646, in parser_f
    return _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)

  File "/home/swhan/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 401, in _read
    data = parser.read()

  File "/home/swhan/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 939, in read
    ret = self._engine.read(nrows)

  File "/home/swhan/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 1508, in read
    data = self._reader.read(nrows)

  File "pandas/parser.pyx", line 848, in pandas.parser.TextReader.read (pandas/parser.c:10415)

  File "pandas/parser.pyx", line 870, in pandas.parser.TextReader._read_low_memory (pandas/parser.c:10691)

  File "pandas/parser.pyx", line 924, in pandas.parser.TextReader._read_rows (pandas/parser.c:11437)

  File "pandas/parser.pyx", line 911, in pandas.parser.TextReader._tokenize_rows (pandas/parser.c:11308)

  File "pandas/parser.pyx", line 2024, in pandas.parser.raise_parser_error (pandas/parser.c:27037)

CParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: out of memory
```

In fact, the csv file consists of two columns, one for ID, and another for long text information for each ID, a subset of which looks like this or:

```
id  text
12  python pandas read data of the form ...
13  how to remove file does not exist error ...
41  pandas unable to find files ...
99  issue with python is not a simple problem ...
```

[csv file picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qNcZj.jpg)

Isn't there any way to read this file into pandas' dataframe object? By the way, my desktop has 32GB RAM. Thank you in advance!

**Alternative try with the Python code with 'chunksize'**

```
df = pd.DataFrame()
reader = pd.read_csv("10k_2005_2008_file.csv", chunksize=10**3)
for chunk in reader:
    df = pd.concat([df, chunk], ignore_index=True)

df
Out[6]: 
           ID                                               text
0      255618  ['ITEM1.BUSINESSIn this annual report onForm10...
1       94740  ['Item 1. Business.GeneralCommunity CapitalCor...
2      145200  ['ITEM 1.BUSINESSGeneralCommunityBank Shares o...
3      145201  ['ITEM 1. BUSINESSGeneralCommunity  Bank Share...
4      145202  ['Item 1. BusinessGeneralCommunity Bank Shares...
5      145203  ['Item1.BusinessGeneralCommunityBank Shares of...
6      221548  ['Item1.BusinessOverviewTravelzoo Inc. (the Co...
7      121633  ['Item1. BusinessGeneralSterling Financial Cor...
8      172796  ['Item 1. BusinessGeneralWe are a Maryland cor...
9      172797  ['Item 1. BusinessGeneralWe are a Maryland cor...
10     121632  ['Item 1.BusinessGeneralCompanyGrowthProfitabi...
11      28995  ['ITEM 1. Business.(Dollars in millions)We res...
12      28994  ['ITEM 1. Business.GeneralAt December31, 2004,...
13      28997  ['Item1.Business.GeneralService Corporation In...
14      28996  ['ITEM 1. Business.GeneralAt December31, 2004,...
15     118636  ['Item1.BusinessWe are a broadcast company pri...
16      28993  ['ITEM 1. Business.GeneralAt December31, 2004,...
17     101760  ['ITEM1.BUSINESSCorporateProfileCognex Corpora...
18     145752  ['Item 1: Election of Directors; Nomineesfor D...
19      94744  ['ITEM1.BUSINESS.GeneralCommunityCapital Corpo...
20      28999  ['Item1.Business.GeneralService Corporation In...
21      28998  ['Item1.Business.GeneralService Corporation In...
22       1868  ['ITEM1.BUSINESSCompany OverviewWe are a world...
23     269745  ['Item1"BusinessThe CompanyThe 2004 Reorganiza...
24     181343  ['ITEM 1.  BUSINESSMKS Instruments, Inc. ("the...
25     220768  ['ITEM1. BUSINESS  General  The Company  Sierr...
26     181345  ['Item1.BusinessMKS Instruments, Inc. (the Com...
27     145750  ['Item1. Business   BurlingtonNorthern Santa F...
28     181346  ['Item1.BusinessMKS Instruments, Inc. (the Com...
29     145751  ['Item 1: Election of Directors; Nominees for ...
      ...                                                ...
19303   26477  ['ITEM1.BUSINESS  Precision Castparts Corp. (P...
19304  256145  ['Item1 Business,Item1A Risk Factors, and Item...
19305  222814  ['Item1. Business.  General  Our company, Rock...
19306   73641  ['ITEM 1. BUSINESSGENERALTexas Regional Bancsh...
19307   66997  ['ITEM 1. BUSINESSOur CompanyWe are a leading ...
19308   66996  ['ITEM 1. BUSINESSOur CompanyWe are a leading ...
19309   66994  ['ITEM1. BUSINESS  Our Company  We are a leadi...
19310   66993  ['ITEM 1. BUSINESS   Our CompanyWe are a leadi...
19311    7929  ['Item1. Business(a)General development of bus...
19312  114251  ['Item1.BusinessGeneralTerra Nitrogen Company,...
19313  114250  ['Item1 BusinessGeneralTerra Nitrogen Company,...
19314  198077  ['Item1. BusinessGeneral DescriptionTeam Finan...
19315  162197  ["ITEM 1. BUSINESSWintrust Financial Corporati...
19316   25524  ['Item 1. BusinessEnvironmental. Contamination...
19317  190015  ['Item 1. Description of Business.GeneralEVCI ...
19318    5634  ['Item 1.BusinessGeneral  CDI Corp. (the Compa...
19319    5635  ['Item 1.BusinessGeneral  CDI Corp. (the Compa...
19320  190932  ['ITEM 1.   BUSINESSORGANIZATION AND GENERAL B...
19321  190933  ['ITEM 1.   BUSINESSORGANIZATION AND GENERAL B...
19322    5632  ['Item 1.BusinessGeneral  CDI Corp., (the Comp...
19323    5633  ['Item 1.BusinessGeneral  CDI Corp. (the Compa...
19324   38349  ['Item 1. BusinessThe CompanyNatures SunshineP...
19325  222816  ['Item1 above.Weoperate on a 52/53 week fiscal...
19326  222815  ['Item1. Business.GeneralOur company, Rockwell...
19327  213793  ['Item1.BusinessTvia,Inc. is a fabless semicon...
19328    8489  ['ITEM1.BusinessCrown Crafts, Inc. (the Compan...
19329  224247  ['Item1.Business   GENERAL   We are asolutions...
19330  198076  ['Item1. BusinessGeneral DescriptionTeam Finan...
19331   34149  ['Item1. BusinessVF Corporation, organized in ...
19332   34148  ['Item1 in PartI, Items 5, 6, 7, 7A, 8 and 9A ...

[19333 rows x 2 columns]
```

Comment: Can you show output when using `chunksize`?

Comment: I edited the above post with python code with 'chunksize'. Thanks!

Comment: Use a smaller chunk size. Maybe 1000?

Comment: Yes, when I use a smaller chunk size, it seems work fine. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

[Pandas docs says](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/merging.html):

> **Note** It is worth noting however, that concat (and therefore append) makes a full copy of the data, and that constantly reusing
>   this function can create a significant performance hit. If you need to
>   use the operation over several datasets, use a list comprehension.

```
frames = [ process_your_file(f) for f in files ]
result = pd.concat(frames)
```

So try this approach:

```
reader = pd.read_csv("10k_2005_2008_file.csv", chunksize=10**3)
df = pd.concat([x for x in reader], ignore_index=True)
```